# Winforms Listbox, how to make a displaymember work despite the Drawmode being OwnerDrawFixed?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, bindinglist

I've been trying to have different colored items in my listbox and stumbled across [this Link](https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/winform/c-program-to-change-the-color-of-listbox-item-at-run-time/). I tried implementing it into my project. But now I have a big problem: The Data source of the listbox is a Binding List and has a working Displaymember and everything, but after inserting this (which is necessary for the color change to work):

```
lbx_robots.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

The displaymember seems to get ignored and instead of seeing the Name of the Item, i just see Robogotchi.Robot, so the same as when I have no Display member at all.

The class wherein most of the problem code lies:

```
public Robogotchi()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //test BEGIN; DELETE LATER
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.State = Robot.stateofrobot.Einwandfrei;
        robot.Name = "test";
        int abc = Convert.ToInt32(robot.State);
        robotlist.Add(robot);
        lbx_robots.DataSource = robotlist;
        lbx_robots.DisplayMember = "Name";
        lbx_robots.Refresh();


        //test END; DELETE LATER

        //stuff to change the color of listbox items
        //lbx_robots.BackColor = Color.Beige;
        lbx_robots.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
        lbx_robots.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(listBox1_SetColor);
    }
```

And here is what appears in my listbox once I run it:
[Screenshot of my Listbox with displaymember not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO7JB.png)

Comment: You should post code of `listBox1_SetColor` but my gut feeling is that you're following the example you linked. In that case when you have the `Robot` object then you do NOT want to call `ToString()` but directly read its `Name` property (when ownerdraw it's up to you, the control won't do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I just solved it:
In the code from the site there is a line that says

```
.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

And when I changed it to:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString((((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index] as Robot).Name,
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
```

It worked.